# Notifications in Notification Center disappearing after opening one of them

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have a server that sends users many push notifications at any single time. Let's say 5 notifications are send to the phone. If I open one of them, all other notifications disappears.

How do I make the only one that is clicked, disappear. I look through the tutorials and done everything correctly. Is it something to do with the badge number or do I need to assign a special ID to every notification?

I can't find any solution on the web and I am surprise no one else faces this issue.

Ps. I am using Ionic Framework to build my app

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? There are apps that do not have this issue

Answer (score 0):

> > " I am surprise no one else faces this issue."

Many many people have faced this same issue, its a mystery why Apple don't add more functionality in this area after so many years, but the situation is that you can't programatically delete just a single notification. You either delete all of them or none of them.

Comment: It can't be. There are some ios apps like gmail where a single notification from the notification centre is removed if its click on, and the rest of the gmail notifications still remains.

Perhaps, this can be done in native and not ionic framework. :(

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce that using gmail - I sent 3 emails and got 3 notifications, then opened the notification center and clicked on the middle of the 3. When I went back to the notification center after being directed to gmail all 3 had been deleted. How did you see it happen?